# ReSharper doesn't apply type layout

Tags: resharper, resharper-10.0

I've probably missed an extremely obvious setting, but no matter what I try, I can't get ReSharper to apply any type layout (neither my own nor the default ones).

(using ReSharper 10.0.0.2 Ultimate trial)

I just made a quick type layout in the visual designer, this is the generated XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Patterns xmlns="urn:schemas-jetbrains-com:member-reordering-patterns">
  <TypePattern DisplayName="Default">
    <Entry DisplayName="Fields">
      <Entry.Match>
        <Kind Is="Field" />
      </Entry.Match>
    </Entry>
    <Entry DisplayName="Methods">
      <Entry.Match>
        <Kind Is="Method" />
      </Entry.Match>
    </Entry>
  </TypePattern>
</Patterns>
```

I always did a full code cleanup, but even with a custom profile (as seen below, only "apply file template" selected) nothing is reordered:
[image]

Edit:
It **seems** Resharper did move certain things in **some** files of my project, but by no means were all fields/methods (no matter what access or static) put in the right order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it indeed was something obvious. Apparently the regions in code (despite they grouped methods/properties already) prevented the layout from being applied.